# Why does git mark as untracked a .gitignored folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

[image]

I haven't previously committed this folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `.gitignore` is in the `code` folder.

Move `.gitgnore` to the top folder of your repository.

[image]